# How do I update a stock number from cart items qty in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a shop system, so when a customer orders some items and tries to save them to the database, I want to subtract the preview product qty from the new qty ordered.

My API is sending that cart items

```
const cartItems = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'item one',
    price: 12.99,
    qty: 6,
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: 'item three',
    price: 9.99,
    qty: 10,
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'item two',
    price: 6.99,
    qty: 2,
  },
]
```

And my MongoDB return this value, so how do I substract stock number from qty?

```
const products =  await Product.find({})
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'item one',
        price: 12.99,
        stock: 14,
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        name: 'item two',
        price: 6.99,
        stock: 78,
      },
      {
        _id: 3,
        name: 'item three',
        price: 9.99,
        stock: 54,
      },
]
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'item one',
        price: 12.99,
        stock: 8,
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        name: 'item two',
        price: 6.99,
        stock: 76,
      },
      {
        _id: 3,
        name: 'item three',
        price: 9.99,
        stock: 44,
      },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a naive double nested loop could be sufficient for iterating both arrays and computing a new products array.

```
const newProducts = products.map((product) => ({
  ...product,
  stock:
    product.stock -
    (cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id)?.qty || 0)
}));
```

```js
const cartItems = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "item one",
    price: 12.99,
    qty: 6
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "item three",
    price: 9.99,
    qty: 10
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "item two",
    price: 6.99,
    qty: 2
  }
];

const products = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "item one",
    price: 12.99,
    stock: 14
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "item two",
    price: 6.99,
    stock: 78
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "item three",
    price: 9.99,
    stock: 54
  }
];

const newProducts = products.map((product) => ({
  ...product,
  stock:
    product.stock -
    (cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id)?.qty || 0)
}));

console.log(newProducts);
```

A more optimal method would be to precompute a map of quantities by id for `O(1)` lookups for an overall `O(n)` runtime complexity (*as opposed to the `O(n^2)` of the double-nested loop above*).

```
const quantityMap = cartItems.reduce(
  (quantities, { _id, qty }) => ({
    ...quantities,
    [_id]: qty || 0
  }),
  {}
);

const newProducts = products.map((product) => ({
  ...product,
  stock: product.stock - (quantityMap[product._id] || 0)
}));
```

```js
const cartItems = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "item one",
    price: 12.99,
    qty: 6
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "item three",
    price: 9.99,
    qty: 10
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "item two",
    price: 6.99,
    qty: 2
  }
];

const products = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "item one",
    price: 12.99,
    stock: 14
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "item two",
    price: 6.99,
    stock: 78
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "item three",
    price: 9.99,
    stock: 54
  }
];

const quantityMap = cartItems.reduce(
  (quantities, { _id, qty }) => ({
    ...quantities,
    [_id]: qty || 0
  }),
  {}
);

const newProducts = products.map((product) => ({
  ...product,
  stock: product.stock - (quantityMap[product._id] || 0)
}));

console.log(newProducts);
```